# Problem combining lists with lapply() function

Tags: r, list, dataframe

I'm struggling trying to find a error in my R-code. I have a list called lst such as:

```
lst:

A   double[1 x 896]   1 2 3 4...
B   double[1 x 1025]   0 4 7 9...
C   double[1 x 1335]   1 2 3 4...
```

I'm trying to combine those elements two by two, which have the same column name. I'm using the code (suggested in [Combine multiple data frame with coincident columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57761377/combine-multiple-data-frame-with-coincident-columns/57761397#57761397)).

```
do.call(rbind, lapply(c(lst[j],lst[i]), subset, select = Reduce(intersect, lapply(c(lst[j],lst[i]), colnames))))
```

When I combine A and B, everything works fine:

```
do.call(rbind, lapply(c(lst[1],lst[2]), subset, select = Reduce(intersect, lapply(c(lst[1],lst[2]), colnames))))
```

But when I try to combine A and C

```
do.call(rbind, lapply(c(lst[1],lst[3]), subset, select = Reduce(intersect, lapply(c(lst[1],lst[3]), colnames))))
```

I get the error

```
Error in x[subset & !is.na(subset), vars, drop = drop] : subscript out of bounds
```

The problem comes from:

```
lapply(c(lst[1],lst[3]), subset, select = Reduce(intersect, lapply(c(lst[1],lst[3]), colnames)))
```

Does anyone have an idea about what is happening?

Comment: I think you may need `combn` here

Comment: @akrun: I didn't understand you.

Comment: I'm unclear on what the column names you mean here are - is `lst` a list of dataframes or a list of vectors? Your example suggests it is the latter

Comment: @CalumYou: It is a list of dataframes and the columns are named.

Answer (score 1):

I just solved the problem. Writing

```
aux <- c(lst[j],lst[i])
do.call(rbind, lapply(aux, subset, select = Reduce(intersect, lapply(aux, colnames))))
```

Instead of

```
do.call(rbind, lapply(c(lst[j],lst[i]), subset, select = Reduce(intersect, lapply(c(lst[j],lst[i]), colnames))))
```

In fact, I don't know what is the difference but the first one worked. If anyone have some insight, please let me know.